# Retrieving All Sub Site with Sharepoint Object Model Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, object-model, sub-site

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

 using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;

 using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SPSite mySite = SPControl.GetContextSite(mySiteUrl);
        SPWebCollection subSites = mySite.AllWebs;

            for (int i=0;i<subSites.Count;i++)
            {
                SPListCollection lists = subSites[i].Lists;

                for (int j=0;j<lists.Count;j++)
                {
                    Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(subSites[i].Title) + " :: " +
                    SPEncode.HtmlEncode(lists[j].Title) + "<BR>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Error:
http://1drv.ms/1ydER2Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SPControl.GetContextSite Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spcontrol.getcontextsite%28v=office.12%29.aspx) expects [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter, so replace the line:

```
 SPSite mySite = SPControl.GetContextSite(mySiteUrl);
```

with:

```
var site = new SPSite(mySiteUrl);
```

Secondly, in order to utilize [SPEncode class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587531%28v=office.11%29.aspx) add namespace declaration:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
```

Thirdly, there is no need at all to use [HtmlTextWriter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) since it is a **Console** app(!)

**Fixed example**

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
     foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
     {
          foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
          {
             Console.WriteLine("{0}::{1}",web.Title,list.Title);    
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks So much i hope you've good resources you can send as i'm totally new to this

Comment: Ahmed, since you have difficulties with this relatively simple example, I would strongly suggest you to take some courses about SharePoint development (e.g. from Pluralsight) or get a book, for example Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2013

Comment: Good i just started pluralsight yesterday and i built the whole system with jsom its the first time i need object model

Comment: And thats all for creating a list from saved custom list template i still dunno if its gonna work or not thats why im trying OM it failed with csom and of course it cant be with jsom

Comment: Do keep in mind that all SPWeb objects accessed through the AllWebs collection need to be disposed.